# WCF - Handling request from multiple clients

Tags: wcf, clients

My WCF service library is hosted as a Windows Service and is supposed to handle requests from multiple clients.
One request that clients are going to make frequently is pretty resource intensive.

I have two doubts pertaining to above scenerio:

1. How a WCF service handles multiple client's request?
2. Is there any WCF configuration to make the process efficient?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your default scenario, the WCF service host (the thing hosting your service class) will create a new instance of your service class for each request that comes in, and lets that handle the request ("per-call" activation).

You can tweak the maximum number of those concurrently active service class instances using the `serviceThrottling` behavior on your server.

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="ThrottledServiceBehavior">
            <serviceThrottling 
                maxConcurrentCalls="25" 
                maxConcurrentSessions="25"
                maxConcurrentInstances="25"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
```

There's a really good explanation of the options of the service throttling behavior and its default values in Kenny Wolf's [blog post here](https://kennyw.com/?p=150).

Also, setting of the `InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode` on your service class (that implements the service contract) have a strong influence on how your service will handle concurrency and multiple requests.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall, 
                 ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
class YourServiceClass : IYourService
{
  .....
}
```

`InstanceContextMode` should be `PerCall` (each calling request gets a new, separate instance) and then `ConcurrencyMode` can be `Single` (which is the easiest to develop).

`InstanceContextMode` could also be `PerSession` if you need a session-based approach (not very common), or `Single` (your service class would a singleton - highly discouraged to use this, unless you absolutely, positively have to and know about all the quirks and problems with it!).

`ConcurrencyMode` could also be `Reentrant` (only relevant for duplex contracts and bindings) or `Multiple` (multithreaded singleton service class - highly risky and difficult to develop!).

Marc